# Triidon DXA Error | ttm-prepare.ps1 | Get -TtmcdTopologyType is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program

Tags: dxa, web8, sdl-tridion, web8-cu1

I am getting below error while trying to install DXA by starting with the ttm-prepare.ps1 script.

[image]

I am running the powershell as administrator and also did the `set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Can you please point me to the reason for this erro and what script/file do I need to include for such cmdlets to be recognized by powershell ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer for the Content Manager installs a Powershell module. You can check if this was done by typing `Get-Module -ListAvailable` in the Powershell. On my system, this shows quite a lot of Windows modules, and then at the bottom of the listing, the following:

```
Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\PowerShellModules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     9.0.0.0    Tridion.ContentManager.Automation   {Clear-TcmPublicationTarget, Get-TcmApplicationIds, Get-TcmPublishTransaction, Get-TcmQueueInfo...}
Binary     9.0.0.0    Tridion.ContentManager.Server.Au... {Convert-TcmPublishStates, Convert-TcmBinaries, Find-TcmMissingBinaries, Find-TcmOrphanBinaries...}
Binary     9.0.0.0    Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation  {Add-TtmCdEnvironment, Add-TtmCdTopology, Add-TtmCmEnvironment, Add-TtmWebApplication...}
```

It's possible to run the cms-import.ps1 script from a different computer, but then you'll have to take care of some of the steps by hand. Read the comments at the top of cms-import.ps1. where it says:

> Because the script uses Topology Manager cmdlets, it is easiest to run it on the SDL Web 8 CM Server.
> It is possible to run it on another machine if it has Topology Manager cmdlets installed and TRIDION_TTM_SERVICEURL environment variable set.
> Alternatively, the noTopologyManager switch can be used to suppress creation of mappings in Topology Manager.

So, in general, you should probably prefer to run these scripts on the Content Manager, unless you are in an enviromnent where this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Dominic. This was super helpful. Also, luckily I found your blog post: http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/finding-your-way-around-the-sdl-web-8-cmdlets  with full details over the SDL Web CMDLETS. 

Thank you very much for the help and clear explanation!